# MDC Web: How to remove the blank space between cards

Tags: material-components, material-components-web

I have a website that displays a large grid of cards like so:

[image: Grid of cards]

The problem I'm having is that there is usually a **large gap under each card** and I don't know how to fix this. I want the cards to be fitted together like a collage or a puzzle.

[Here](https://github.com/Richienb/richienb.github.io/blob/development/src/index.html#L237) is a link to the source code of the first card.

If you have any questions or requests, please ask me in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flexbox it can help you drag white spaces to make it even with other rows that contain more contents.

Comment: What extra CSS rules do I need to add and to what elements?

Comment: My goal was not to make the cards bigger but to fit the cards together like a puzzle

Comment: yes it can make your page look like pinterest site! For starters:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I have been trying to do this for at least half an hour to no avail. Could you please open a pull request on my repository? It is here: https://github.com/Richienb/richienb.github.io

Comment: I am busy at the moment to go through your code but am sure this will help a lot!
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_image_gallery

Comment: For some reason, when setting `display:flex`, the cards weirdly squash together or stretch out their white space